# Getting rid of Edge, its accumulated temporary internet files, and related issues

Tags: windows-installer

I used the Winaero macro to disable Edge. Then I painstakingly deleted the Microsoft.Microsoft Edge folders in both AppData and Packages. But the program still exists, and it still accumulates temporary internet files that I can't locate and delete -- 123 MB at the moment. And there still are side windows with black backgrounds that display messages in white or yellow. How can I get rid of that as well, please? Also, the computer tends spontaneously to highlight text in e-mails and Word, so that when I strike a character, everything I've already typed is deleted. I don't wish to go back to Windows 7, which had its own problems, and which won't be supported after 2020. So how do I get rid of Edge completely and solve the other above enumerated issues, please? Thanks!

Comment: "Internet Explorer", in the sense that most people mean it rather than the sense that Microsoft means it, is partially integrated into Windows and used by Windows for it to do it's usual tasks. There is no getting rid of it in it's entirety.

Comment: Split multiple questions into different posts. Your text related issues should be addressed as another, separate ask.

Comment: Thankfully, Windows 10 is self-healing enough to likely make this an exercise in futility, especially with its essentially continuous upgrade path. Just turn it off...

Answer (score 1):

Windows features allows you to turn on or off features of windows

To access it type **Windows Key + R** then type in

```
OptionalFeatures.exe
```

then search though the features and then uncheck the Microsoft edge box or internet explorer box